# Writing the contents of large queues to multiple files

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, queue, thread-safety

I am writing a multiprocessing program which involves n number of processes filling m number of queues which are shared between them. The contents of each queue then needs to be written to a file corresponding to the queue and this is causing me some problems.

I didn't think this was a very hard problem so my first approach was to simply wait until after I had joined all the processes and then iterate over the queues they had generated and write the contents of them to their corresponding files. This worked, mostly, except [due to inherent limitations of how large a queue can get](https://sopython.com/canon/82/programs-using-multiprocessing-hang-deadlock-and-never-complete/) this failed when large queues were generated and it caused my program to hang.

The approach I'm trying at the moment is to spawn an additional process with the sole function which continually iterates over the queues and writes any values inserted into them to their corresponding files but I'm having some troubles getting this to work as I'm not particularly experienced with multiprocessing (or Python).

This is what I'm trying at the moment which with my understanding of what each line should be doing. I'm not sure if this would be a good approach here but either way it isn't working at the moment and I am aware it is also very bad Python :)

```
def _write_files(self, output_buffers):
    while True: # Run continuously
        for expr in self._expr_file_names: # Iterate over all the queues
            while True: # Run until we run out of queue elements or the end of queue is signaled
                if output_buffers[expr].empty(): # If there are no elements left in the queue, break and try the next one
                    break

                line = output_buffers[expr].get()

                if line is None: # None signals the end of the queue so return if we find this
                    return

                self._output_files[self._expr_file_names[expr]].write(line)
```

Additionally, here is the code which I wrote in my first attempt at solving this problem which ran after all the processes had been joined and worked most of the time.

```
def _write_buffers(self, output_buffers):
    for expr in self._expr_file_names:
        for line in iter(output_buffers[expr].get, None):
            self._output_files[self._expr_file_names[expr]].write(line)
```